# Segmentation fault / glibc detected when creating shared library

Tags: c++, multithreading, segmentation-fault, pthreads, shared-libraries

EDITS----------------I tried with gcc-4.8.1 and still the same error.-------------I am trying to implement a simple matrix multiplication example using pthreads via a shared library. But I get this error when I try to create a shared library:

```
g++ -shared -o libMatmul.so matmul.o 
collect2: ld terminated with signal 11 [Segmentation fault], core dumped
```

Here is the code I am using:
matmul.h:

```
#ifndef matmul_h__
#define matmul_h__
#define SIZE 10 

typedef struct {

int dim;
int slice;
} matThread;

int num_thrd;
int A[SIZE][SIZE], B[SIZE][SIZE], C[SIZE][SIZE];
int m[SIZE][SIZE];
extern void init_matrix(int m[SIZE][SIZE]);
extern void print_matrix(int m[SIZE][SIZE]);
extern void* multiply(void* matThread);

#endif
```

matmul.c:

```
extern "C"
 {
    #include <pthread.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
 }
#include <iostream>
#include "matmul.h"

using namespace std ;
matThread* s=NULL;
// initialize a matrix
void init_matrix(int m[SIZE][SIZE])
{
  int i, j, val = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
  for (j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
  m[i][j] = val++;
}

void print_matrix(int m[SIZE][SIZE])
{
  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    cout<<"\n\t|" ;
    for (j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
      cout<<m[i][j] ;
      cout<<"|";
    }
}
 // thread function: taking "slice" as its argument
void* multiply(void* param)
{
  matThread* s = (matThread*)param;   // retrive the slice info
  int slice1=s->slice;
  int D= s->dim=10;
  int from = (slice1 * D)/num_thrd; // note that this 'slicing' works fine
  int to = ((slice1+1) * D)/num_thrd; // even if SIZE is not divisible by num_thrd
  int i,j,k;
   cout<<"computing slice  " << slice1<<" from row "<< from<< " to " <<to-1<<endl;
  for (i = from; i < to; i++)
  {  
    for (j = 0; j < D; j++)
    {
      C[i][j] = 0;
      for ( k = 0; k < D; k++)
      C[i][j] += A[i][k]*B[k][j];
    }
   }
  cout<<" finished slice "<<slice1<<endl;
  return NULL;
 }
```

main.c:

```
extern "C"
{
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
}
#include <iostream>
#include "matmul.h"
using namespace std;

// Size by SIZE matrices
// number of threads
matThread* parm=NULL;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  pthread_t* thread;  // pointer to a group of threads
  int i;
   if (argc!=2)
  {
   cout<<"Usage:"<< argv[0]<<" number_of_threads"<<endl;
   exit(-1);
  }
  num_thrd = atoi(argv[1]);
  init_matrix(A);
  init_matrix(B);
  thread = (pthread_t*) malloc(num_thrd*sizeof(pthread_t));
  matThread *parm = new matThread();
  for (i = 0; i < num_thrd; i++)
  {
parm->slice=i;
    // creates each thread working on its own slice of i
    if (pthread_create (&thread[i], NULL, multiply, (void*)parm) != 0)
    {
      cerr<<"Can't create thread"<<endl;
      free(thread);
      exit(-1);
    }
  }
 for (i = 1; i < num_thrd; i++)
  pthread_join (thread[i], NULL);
   cout<<"\n\n";
   print_matrix(A);
   cout<<"\n\n\t *"<<endl;
   print_matrix(B);
   cout<<"\n\n\t="<<endl;
   print_matrix(C);
   cout<<"\n\n";
   free(thread);

  return 0;

}
```

The commands that I use are:
g++ -c -Wall -fPIC matmul.cpp -o matmul.o and 
g++ -shared -o libMatmul.so matmul.o
The code might look little off because I am passing SIZE(dim) in a struct when its already in #define, but this is how I want it to be implemented. Its a test program for a bigger project that I am doing. 
Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: what version of GCC are you using?

Comment: I tried with gcc 4.1 and it let me creat the shared library but couldn't link it with main. When I tried with gcc-4.6.3, the above stated is the error

Comment: I thought there were some compiler/linker flag when using pthreads. Something like -lpthread.

Comment: When using 4.1, I could create shared lib. And When I execute the command: g++ -L/dir.../ -Wall -o matmul main.cpp -lMatmul -ldl -lpthread I get the glibc detected error. That's again some kind of memory mis-map and segmentation fault.

Comment: Using `gcc (Debian 4.4.5-8) 4.4.5` at least the library can be created succesfully, if creating `matmul.o` using option `-fPIC`. Using option `-pthread` is recommened however when creating multithreaded objects.

Comment: @alk: Were you able to link main.c to shared library after that ? I tried -pthread flag when building .so file and still the same error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you're mixing a lot of C and C++ idioms (calling `free` and `new` for instance) and you're not using any C++ library/STL features (like a `std::vector` or `std::list` instead of a C array), so while your code is 'technically' valid (minus some bugs) it's not good practice to mix C and C++ like that, there are many small idiosyncratic differences between C and C++ (syntax, compilation and linkage differences for example) that can add confusion to the code if it's not explicitly clear to the intentions.

That being said, I've made some changes to your code to make it `C++98` compatible (and fix the bugs):

start `matmul.h`:

```
#ifndef matmul_h__
#define matmul_h__
#define SIZE 10
#include <pthread.h>

typedef struct matThread {
    int slice;
    int dim;
    pthread_t handle;

    matThread() : slice(0), dim(0), handle(0) {}
    matThread(int s) : slice(s), dim(0), handle(0) {}
    matThread(int s, int d) : slice(s), dim(d), handle(0) {}
} matThread;

// explicitly define as extern (for clarity)
extern int num_thrd;
extern int A[SIZE][SIZE];
extern int B[SIZE][SIZE];
extern int C[SIZE][SIZE];
extern void init_matrix(int m[][SIZE]);
extern void print_matrix(int m[][SIZE]);
extern void* multiply(void* matThread);

#endif
```

start `matmul.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream> // <stdio.h>
#include "matmul.h"

int num_thrd = 1;
int A[SIZE][SIZE];
int B[SIZE][SIZE];
int C[SIZE][SIZE];

// initialize a matrix
void init_matrix(int m[][SIZE])
{
    int i, j, val;
    for (i = 0, val = -1; i < SIZE; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
            m[i][j] = ++val;
        }
    }
}

void print_matrix(int m[][SIZE])
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        std::cout << "\n\t|"; // printf
        for (j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
            std::cout << m[i][j];
        }
        std::cout << "|"; // printf
    }
}

// thread function: taking "slice" as its argument
void* multiply(void* param)
{
    matThread* s = (matThread*)param;   // retrive the slice info
    int slice1 = s->slice;
    int D = s->dim = 10;
    int from = (slice1 * D) / num_thrd; // note that this 'slicing' works fine
    int to = ((slice1+1) * D) / num_thrd; // even if SIZE is not divisible by num_thrd
    int i, j, k;
    std::cout << "computing slice " << slice1 << " from row " << from << " to " << (to-1) << std::endl; // printf
    for (i = from; i < to; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < D; j++) {
            C[i][j] = 0;
            for ( k = 0; k < D; k++) {
                C[i][j] += A[i][k]*B[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << " finished slice " << slice1 << std::endl; // printf
    return NULL;
}
```

start `main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib> // atoi .. if C++11, you could use std::stoi in <string>
#include "matmul.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        std::cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " number_of_threads" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    } else {
        num_thrd = std::atoi(argv[1]);
    }
    matThread mt[num_thrd];
    int i = 0;
    init_matrix(A);
    init_matrix(B);
    for (i = 0; i < num_thrd; i++) {
        mt[i].slice = i;
        // creates each thread working on its own slice of i
        if (pthread_create(&mt[i].handle, NULL, &multiply, static_cast<void*>(&mt[i])) != 0) {
            printf("Can't create thread\n");
            return -1;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < num_thrd; i++) {
        pthread_join(mt[i].handle, NULL);
    }
    std::cout << "\n\n";
    print_matrix(A);
    std::cout << "\n\n\t *\n";
    print_matrix(B);
    std::cout << "\n\n\t=\n";
    print_matrix(C);
    std::cout << "\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

To compile and use it you'll need to do the following commands:

```
g++ -c -Wall -fPIC matmul.cpp -o matmul.o
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,libMatmul.so -o libMatmul.so.1 matmul.o
ln /full/path/to/libMatmul.so.1 /usr/lib/libMatmul.so
g++ main.cpp -o matmul -Wall -L. -lMatmul -pthread
```

Note that for your system to be able to find and link against the shared library you've just created, you'll need to ensure it's in your distro's lib folder (like `/usr/lib/`). You can copy/move it over, create a link to it (or a sym link via `ln -s` if you can't do hard links), and if you don't want to copy/move/link it, you can also ensure your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is properly set to include the build directory.

As I said; your code is NOT inherently C++ aside from the few print statements (`std::cout`, etc), and changing the C++ code (`std::cout` to `printf` and some other minor things for example) you could compile this as standard `C99` code. I'm not 100% sure how the rest of your shared library will be designed so I didn't change the structure of the lib code (i.e. the functions you have) but if you wanted this code to be 'more C++' (i.e. with classes/namespaces, STL, etc.), you'd basically need to redesign your code, but given the context of your code, I don't think that's absolutely necessary unless you have a specific need for it.

I hope that can help.

Comment: Thanks a ton for helping me out here. But I still get the same error!. It still says `collect2: error: ld terminated with signal 11 [Segmentation fault], core dumped` . Did it compile for you? I am using gcc-4.8.1

Comment: OK wait, it works with gcc 4.1.2. I don't understand why though!! Anyway Thanks a lot for the help. Yes, if its not too much to ask, can you also put up for c++ with 2 threads acting? I just wanna be sure with what I am doing. I think there is a race condition when calling `pthread_create` because whenever I call for 2 threads only the last thread is active. I think `mt.slice = i` gets updated to 1 before the value of 0 is used.

Comment: I do know there are some updates to 4.8.1 that 'might' make this compile differently (as a shared library); I'm doing my own research on this as I use different versions of gcc, so I'll post any thing I find as to why it might not compile on the newer version. I'll edit my post in a bit for the C++ additions as well.

Comment: I've edited my answer to be 'more C++', but keep in mind that your code doesn't really make use of any 'C++ features' (as explained in the answer). I also fixed the 'race' condition bug that was causing the threads to skip over a matrix. Note that there's not a huge difference between this C++ based code and the original C based code I posted, but let me know if anything in the code doesn't make since :)

Comment: You're the man! I would buy you a lunch if I knew you! Thanks a ton :)
One last question. Is there a way to create an array for slice instead of "array of structures"? say slice[2] inside struct and mt.slice[i] = i; How can I fetch this value inside multiply function definition ?

Comment: No problem, glad I could help out :) As per your question, I'm a little confused on what your asking...are you meaning like taking more of the thread create logic/code (from main.cpp) and putting that into the `multiply` thread function?

Comment: No. What if I don't want to modify any other elements of the struct but slice ? Slice should be the only element to update in the struct. So, I thought I can create, say, slice[4] (4 threads) inside the struct and update that in the for loop as mt.slice[i]=i instead of mt[i].slice=i ? How do I access slice inside multiply function ?.The thing is, I have a lot of other variables inside structure in my original code that I don't want to change but just the slice.

Comment: Ok I see what you're meaning; it is possible but would require some redesign of the code, not a lot but still more than I can post in a comment. It might be better to post it as a new question that way more could be posted/explained. If I'm understanding what you want from the code though it sounds like you might be wanting to take most of the 'matmul.cpp/h' and some of the 'main.cpp' code and put that into a class (instead of a struct); this would let you operate only on the info you want to operate on. It could be done without a class as well but still requires a redesign.

Comment: Alright. I created a separate structure that has only those varying elements and passed to that function. It took some redesign of the code but its working! Thanks a lot again for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Should

```
 for (i = 1; i < num_thrd; i++)
```

not be

```
 for (i = 0; i < num_thrd; i++)
```

You created num_thrd threads, but did not join all of them, therefore, a race condition is created as you're trying to read the data before the thread is finished.

Comment: You created num_thrd threads, but did not join all of them, therefore, a race condition is created as you're trying to read the data before the thread is finished.

Comment: @robby987:  I am not even able to create .so file. And the edits above are for main.c file. I also tried with -lpthread flag for creating shared library and still same error

Comment: Works on mine. '#!/bin/bash
g++ -c -Wall -fPIC matmul.c -o matmul.o
g++ -shared -o libMatmul.so matmul.o
'